# Pass properties of parent control to children controls

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

I am developing a set of custom controls for a specific application. I want to define properties which is universal over the set of controls for appearance purposes, for argument's sake let's make it `CustomCtrl.AccentColor`

I want to define that same property for my Windows form i.e. `Form1.AccentColor` and when I change it, all the custom controls' `AccentColor` should change, exactly like when I change the `ForeColor` of my form, all labels' and buttons' etc `ForeColor` changes with it.

Is it at all possible to do this or do I have to settle for the effort of looping through all custom controls and changing it one-by-one?

Comment: Can your custom controls inherit from a single base class or your controls have their own base class? For example can all of them inherit from `MyBaseControl` or for example some of them are inheriting from `TextBox`, Some `TreeView`, Some `ComboBox` and ...?

Comment: I usually let the controls inherit from `Control`.

Comment: And you don't have any custom control which inherit from some other class?

Comment: No. I don't really customise controls that need functionality of other controls that I can't easily program myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**

Since you can have a common base class for all your controls as you mentioned in comments, as an option you can create a base class and then add some properties with behavior like [ambient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.ambientproperties(v=vs.110).aspx) properties (like `Font`) to the base control class.

---

**Detailed Answer**

An ambient property is a property on a control that, if not set, is retrieved from the parent control.

In our implementation, we get the value from parent `Form` using `FindForm` method. So in the implementation, when getting the property value, we check if the value equals to default value and if the parent from has the same property, we return the property value of the parent form, otherwise we return the property value of the control itself.

After adding `XXXX` property, in this scenario we also should implement `ShouldSerializeXXXX` and `ResetXXXX` methods to let the designer when serialize the property and how to reset value when you right click on property and choose reset.

**MyBaseControl**

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class MyBaseControl : Control
{
    public MyBaseControl()
    {
        accentColor = Color.Empty;
    }
    private Color accentColor;
    public Color AccentColor
    {
        get
        {
            if (accentColor == Color.Empty && ParentFormHasAccentColor())
                return GetParentFormAccentColor();
            return accentColor;
        }
        set
        {
            if (accentColor != value)
                accentColor = value;
        }
    }
    private bool ParentFormHasAccentColor()
    {
        return this.FindForm() != null &&
               this.FindForm().GetType().GetProperty("AccentColor") != null;
    }
    private Color GetParentFormAccentColor()
    {
        if (ParentFormHasAccentColor())
            return (Color)this.FindForm().GetType()
                               .GetProperty("AccentColor").GetValue(this.FindForm());
        else
            return Color.Red;
    }
    private bool ShouldSerializeAccentColor()
    {
        return this.AccentColor != GetParentFormAccentColor();
    }
    private void ResetAccentColor()
    {
        this.AccentColor = GetParentFormAccentColor();
    }
}
```

**MyBaseForm**

```
public class BaseForm : Form
{
    [DefaultValue("Red")]
    public Color AccentColor { get; set; }
    public BaseForm()
    {
        this.AccentColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

**Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : BaseForm
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. I've learned quite a lot about windows forms today, it's quite interesting and intuitive. It is strange that there are no, or very limited resources about these thing or everything is published under some other obscure topic. MSDN rarely helps in this user interface regard unless you know the inner workings of Visual Studio really well.

Comment: plus, up until recently, my knowledge of inheritance was very lacking, so that also helps quite a bit.

Comment: You are welcome. These are advanced topic of windows forms which usually you don't need them for basic and common tasks, but when you need to perform an advanced task or create a custom control, you will learn this topics.

Comment: By the way, I should share another solution (which is not the direct answer to your question, but is an answer to your requirement.)

Comment: As an option you can create `MyBaseControl` having some properties which you can bind them to you application settings. Then you can create corresponding property in your base form and then in your `Form1` bind these properties o a single settings property. Then your control property will be synchronized with your form property.

Comment: That's a good idea also. There will definitely be cases where I'll remember to use that.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can create inherited class from Control class and define your common properties on there then inheriting your custom controls from that class and use parent property to access container (like Form) and get property value from it

Comment: This seems promising but I really have no clue how to do that. Do you have any advice?