# Visual Studio changes designer generated code when I create a new class inheriting from Form

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, windows-forms-designer

As per recommendation I ask this question in a new thread. The question stems off an answer by Reza given to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36715648/windows-user-form-custom-browsable-properties/36718998?noredirect=1#comment61102540_36718998), where I wanted custom properties to show up in the form's designer.

To accomplish this, I need to create a class, let's call it `BaseForm` and let `BaseForm` inherit from `System.Windows.Forms.Form` and I should add my desired properties to this class and let my user form inherit from `BaseForm`. Like this:

```
public partial class BaseForm : Form
{
    [Browsable(true), Description("test property"), Category("Appearance")]
    public Color bCol { get; set; }
}

public partial class Form1 : BaseForm
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

When I do this, however, Visual Studio changes the designer generated `partial class Form1`, where the `InitializeComponent` etc. is located, to `partial class BaseForm`. This comes with the error that `InitializeComponent` is not in the scope of `Form1` so I change it to this:

```
public partial class BaseForm : Form
{
    [Browsable(true), Description("test property"), Category("Appearance")]
    public Color bCol { get; set; }
    public BaseForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : BaseForm
{
    /*public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }*/
}
```

This is defeating the purpose of having `Form1` inheriting from `BaseForm` because what I see in the designer is `BaseForm` which inherits from `Form`, instead of `Form1` which inherits from `BaseForm` as I wish to do.

Why is Visual Studio doing this and what could I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The designer edits the first class in your file. You have put `BaseForm` as first class in your .cs file.

To solve the problem, make it in a separate file or move the codes for `BaseForm` after `Form1` codes.

In general it's better to keep code of `BaseForm` separate, so it's better to add new form to the project and name it `BaseForm` and add additional properties to the form, then for other forms, add `Inherited Form` or add new `Form` and change the base class name manually.

Comment: Thanks for the great advice. May I ask you to have a look at a closely related question I have asked months ago [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34916114/pass-properties-of-parent-control-to-children-controls) for which I haven't received a definite answer yet?

Comment: You are welcome, sure, I'll take a look at your question and I'll share an answer if I can :)